# Bad opernand Types for binary operator and some other problems?

Tags: java, swing

I am having some error's with my java programming, Please correct errors and edit this code in professional way or please tell me how to correct these error's ?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class grade
{
    public static String inputbasicSal()
    {
        String name="";


        name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"PLEASE ENTER YOUR NAME : ");

        String basicSalary=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"PLEASE ENTER YOUR BASIC SALARY : ");
        int conBasSal=Integer.parseInt(basicSalary);


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"YOUR GRADE IS :"+name);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"YOUR BASIC SALARY IS :"+basicSalary);

        return basicSalary;     
    }

    public static float allowance()
    {
        String Grade=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"PLEASE ENTER YOUR GRADE (1 or 2) : ");
        int congrade=Integer.parseInt(Grade);

            float Allowance;

            if (Grade.equals(1))
            {
                Allowance=inputbasicSal() * (100/10);

            }

            if (Grade.equals(2))
            {
                Allowance=(100/5) * inputbasicSal();
            }

            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"SORRY PLEASE TYPE 1 or 2 :"+Allowance);
            }

            return Allowance;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"YOUR ALLOWANCE IS :"+Allowance);
    }

    public static float totalSal()
    {
        Totalsal=inputbasicSal()+allowance();

        return Totalsal;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"YOUR TOTSL SALARY IS :"+Totalsal);
    }


    public static float tax()
    {
        float Tax=(100/5)*inputbasicSal();

        return Tax;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"YOUR TAX IS :"+Tax);
    }

    public static float net()
    {
        float Net=inputbasicSal()+allowance()-tax();

        return Net; 

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"YOUR NET SALARY IS :"+Net);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        inputbasicSal();
        allowance();
        totalSal();
        tax();
        net();  
    }   
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: Don't post questions telling people to correct your code for you. Ask them what's wrong with it by all means, but "Please correct errors and edit this code in professional way..." isn't how you want to do this on SO.

Comment: Separately: *Say what the errors are.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't compared string properly in your code!

```
Grade.equals("1")
```

AND

```
Grade.equals("2")
```

Next,your code is incorrect in returning values too.

```
Totalsal=inputbasicSal()+allowance();
```

here, return type of inputbasic() is string which is different from other two. So,it's an error.

Please correct it as

```
float Totalsal=Float.parseFloat(inputbasicSal())+allowance();
```

And similarly,for the next two methods!

```
float Tax=(100/5)*Float.parseFloat(inputbasicSal());
```

And,the last one :-

```
float Net=Float.parseFloat(inputbasicSal())+allowance()-tax();
```

Edit your code accordingly!

Comment: its ok, working but its showing error in 

 if (Grade.equals(1))
        {
            Allowance=inputbasicSal() * (100/10);

Bad opernand types for binary "*"

Comment: @Randomdemha-If errors are rectified,please accept the answer!

Comment: Because,there are some other mistakes too! Like,in your if-statement,you have done the same mistake--->`if (Grade.equals(1))
        {
            Allowance=inputbasicSal() * (100/10);

        }

        if (Grade.equals(2))
        {
            Allowance=(100/5) * inputbasicSal();
        }`

Change it to 

`if (Grade.equals(1))
        {
            Allowance=Float.parseFloat(inputbasicSal()) * (100/10);

        }

        if (Grade.equals(2))
        {
            Allowance=(100/5) * Float.parseFloat(inputbasicSal());
        }
`

Comment: Ok last one error Cannot find symbol 
and showing return Allowance

Comment: `return Allowance;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"YOUR ALLOWANCE IS :"+Allowance);`

Change it to 


    `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"YOUR ALLOWANCE IS :"+Allowance);
return Allowance;`

Comment: Frankly to speak,your code wouldn't be made error free as there will still be several errors! Please refer to some good tutuorials before writing code! It can't be rectified more than this on a textual conversation!